# Convert 16 byte IPv6 into colon-separated string

Tags: c

Say I have 16 byte ipv6 address

```
struct in6_addr {
　　uint8_t s6_addr[16];
};
```

How can I convert it into the regular IPv6 colon separated string representation in a cross-platform fashion and without accessing the Internet?

Can I sprintf it in a char* buffer somehow?

Answer (score 5):

use `inet_ntop()`

If you can't.

```
struct in6_addr a;
char buf[40];
...

sprintf(buf,"%02x%02x:%02x%02x:%02x%02x:%02x%02x:%02x%02x:%02x%02x:%02x%02x:%02x%02x",
    a.s6_addr[0], a.s6_addr[1], a.s6_addr[2], a.s6_addr[3],
    a.s6_addr[4], a.s6_addr[5], a.s6_addr[6], a.s6_addr[7],
    a.s6_addr[8], a.s6_addr[9], a.s6_addr[10], a.s6_addr[11],
    a.s6_addr[12], a.s6_addr[13], a.s6_addr[14], a.s6_addr[15]);
```

edit: fixed an index typo

Comment: So there is no need to convert them from any kind of network byte order when using sprintf?

Comment: @Flying-Hat network byte order is most-significant byte first, same order I'm printing them. it I was printing them 4 digits at a time, then yes I'd have to convert, but as the structure is an array of bytes there's no need, I can just pick them in the order needed.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to convert an IPv6 stored in a buffer of 16 bytes (`uint8_t` aka `unsigned char`) is to use the POSIX (also [RFC 2553](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2553#section-6.6)) function `inet_ntop`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void) {
  uint8_t s6_addr[16] = ...;
  char result[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
  if (inet_ntop(AF_INET6, s6_addr, result, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN)) {
    printf("Resolved IPv6: %s\n", result);
    return 0;
  } else {
    printf("Oopsy, can't understand IPv6 address: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }
}
```

The main advantage in using `inet_ntop()` is that the formatting is consistent with IPv6 formatting guidelines. For example, if the address contains a stretch of 0s, then a `sprintf()` code will generate something like this: "`2600:1f16:0000:0000:9126:08c2:1b79:904c`", while `inet_ntop()` will correctly say "`2600:1f16::9126:08c2:1b79:904c`".

Comment: [RFC 3493](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3493) obsoleted RFC 2553.  The [**Address Conversion Functions**](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3493#section-6.3) moved to 6.3, but it seems substantially unchanged.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - thanks for checking that out  my man page said 2553 and I went to the extra effort of verifying it and linking, but didn't check for obsoletion.